# Vercel REST API Artifact Hash

Tags: vercel, vercel-micro

I was checking vercel's REST API documentation and saw this api:

```
HEAD: /v8/artifacts/{hash}
```

What is this the use of this API? Is this API for accessing the build Artifact or something else?

Also Can someone tell where can I find the hash value from? I couldn't find an API that list the available hash.

[Here is the link to the vercel's doc, where this API is mentioned.](https://vercel.com/docs/rest-api/endpoints#check-if-a-cache-artifact-exists)